# Visual Studio - UiPath Standard Activity requires .NET framework

Tags: visual-studio, uipath, uipath-activity

I try to use UiPath Standard Activity Template to create a project in Visual Studio.
Although, I installed requested framework, the project pattern shows this error message.

[image: Template pattern and VS Installer]
Does anyone know, which package I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

As also written [here](https://forum.uipath.com/t/uipath-activity-creator-for-vs2022-net-version-problem/474951/3). You just need to install the .Net Framework:

- Install [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack and Language Packs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978)